# Water droplet movement equation in Electric Field

Tags: electrostatics, water

I am trying to find analytical equations to calculate the Force acting on a water droplet (not a stream) in an external electric field.

Let's say I have an electric field generated due to a ring of charge. One can simulate or calculate to a certain point the electric field generated by it in 3D.

Now, if a water droplet (assuming spherical) is passing through it due to gravitational forces. The forces acting on it are the drag force and gravity. Along with it, there is the electric field force. How would one calculate it, or at least get an idea of its magnitude?

The water droplet is polar and there have been certain high school examples where the water gets deflected. But they only show the stream. Thereby it is debatable it is due to the electrostatic induction or polarity of water. However my example, there is no stream it is just a droplet. So it should be due to the polarity of water?

Link for a stream of water deflection: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaVPO3fXOsw

Follow up, would it be deflected more if the External electric field is generated through a negatively charged ring or with a positively charged ring? Does it affect because the water is polar?

PS: The water is not a stream, so it is not connected to neutral.

PPS: Any suggestions on some Molecular dynamics simulation software that one can use to check the phenomenon?

Comment: The field polarizes the water and the field gradient leads to a force on the polarized droplets. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes, but the force should not be high enough in a uniform electric field to cause motion of the droplet, as the distance between hydrogen and oxygen molecules is very very small.

Comment: The force in a uniform field would be zero, but the field of a charged rod as shown in the video has a very strong gradient. Water droplets are also likely to be slightly charged, which leads to a strong force even in a homogeneous field. This effect is being put to use in the Millikan Oil Drop experiment. What I can't tell you is which effect (polarization or charged liquid) would dominate for droplets. That can be tested by changing the polarity of the field: polarization is always attractive, charges are attractive and repelling, depending on field direction.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yeah  that is what I am hoping an answer on. For droplets. I was able to create a non-uniform field, by changing the charge on the ring (+ve to -ve same magnitude), and I see the droplets moving. So is it because polarization or induce charge. Induce charge should not happen theoretically because water droplet is not connected to anything. How would we prove this?